# Template deduction error

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, stl

Note: pls don't be confused with other Stackoverflow questions that have the same title/errocode -- they are mostly due to missing `#include <string>` but it's not the issue here.

I'm reading [Pretty-print C++ STL containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers) question and downloaed Kerrek's code from his  [GitHub Project cxx-prettyprint](http://louisdx.github.io/cxx-prettyprint/), when I try compile it (my environment is Windows 7, Visual Studio 2013, compiled project as a Console Application "Use Multi-Byte Character Set"), hit a template deduction error.

It's a bit weird as suggested by  Mike Kinghan  in the comment, it does compile compiles and runs fine with the current MSVC++ : [see it online](http://rextester.com/JLBW44338).

I'm confused, there must be something wrong with my configuration. I created a blank new Windows Console Application, and added Kerrek's code in, focus on a vector of string test cast, removed other scenarios such as set/map etc:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{ 
    std::vector<std::string> v;  

    v.push_back("hello, world"); 
    v.push_back("2nd line");
    v.push_back("last line");

    std::cout << v;
}
```

, now hit a error:

> Error 1   error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a
>   right-hand operand of type
>   'std::vector>' (or there is no
>   acceptable conversion)

If I explicitly call the `pretty_print::operator <<`,

```
pretty_print::operator<<(std::cout, v);
```

, hit another template deduction error:

> Error 1   error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
>   &pretty_print::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const
>   pretty_print::print_container_helper
>   &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const
>   pretty_print::print_container_helper
>   &' from 'std::vector>'

It only compiles if the `print_container_helper` is explictily created:

```
pretty_print::print_container_helper<std::vector<std::string>, char, ::std::char_traits<char>, pretty_print::delimiters<std::vector<std::string>, char>>
    vh(v);
pretty_print::operator<<(std::cout, vh);
```

The full code is here: http://rextester.com/RJX76690

Comment: The library as exercised by `ppdemo.cpp` compiles and runs fine with the
current MSVC++, [See it live](http://rextester.com/JLBW44338). Your compiler is older but I suspect your problem lies in your own program, which you haven't posted. Please edit your post to include an [mcve].

Comment: @MikeKinghan I'm confused -- you code does not compile on my Visual Studio 2013! Now the error is in line `  std::cout << "Vector: " << v << std::endl                // vector of strings`, error message: "Error 1 error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Kty>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion) c:\playground\prettyprint\prettyprint\kerrek.cpp 522". what's your project setting? I created a new Console Application then compile with "Use Multi-Byte Character Set"

Comment: Where is your [MCVE]?

Comment: @athos [The program that you says fails for you](http://rextester.com/RJX76690)
when your `// option 1, original code` is compiled [works for me here](http://rextester.com/IUI77727).
`// option 2` was never going to work, as there is no such function.
I'm afraid I can't help you with this any further.

Comment: @MikeKinghan I found the reason -- `decltype(static_cast<typename C::const_iterator(C::*)() const>(&C::begin))` compilation failure, so that the `has_begin_end` is not working. Seems this is a limitation of Visual Studio 2013, in VS2015 it's fine.

Comment: @athos Well spotted :) Suggest you report your bug and fix on the GitHub repo.

Comment: done. :) @MikeKinghan